# How to push a xib from View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, nib

I am making a project in which Their is no storyboard.

I am not much aware about xib's.

I am facing a problem to push ViewControllers from Xib's.

In story board i used to do using:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController......];
```

But here What Should I do:

I am trying with this code:

```
 HomeScreenVC *homeScreen = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeScreen];
[navController pushViewController:homeScreen animated:YES];
```

But it Crashes and the code which works is:

```
 UINavigationController *myNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.signInVC];
[controller presentViewController:myNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am not able to get the right way. Please assist.

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Comment: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<HomeScreenVC: 0x7ffb8b4a36c0>)' @Mr.T

Comment: it says, you are trying to push the homeVC, where homeVC is already there on stack.  What is your current VC ?

Comment: My current VC is WelcomeVC @Mr.T

Comment: does your welcome VC has navigation controller ?

Comment: No it doesn't have..I have no idea of xib. WelcomeVC is pushed from AppDelegate via this code ` 
    WelcomeVC *mainViewController = [[WelcomeVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"WelcomeVC" bundle:nil];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Answer (score 0):

First try to set your viewcontroller with the navigation controller

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//The first view controller
        self.firstController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//The navigation controller
        UINavigationController *navController =  [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.firstController];
        [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

Lets say ViewController is your class which push to your new viewcontroller, try following:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)goToHomeScreen{
     HomeScreenVC *homeScreen = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenVC" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeScreen animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: dont use the same line as posted in the answer. Replace the ViewCOntroller with your WelcomeSCreen VC @RahulMishra

Answer (score 0):

Your code block 1 crashes because:

```
HomeScreenVC *homeScreen = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeScreen];
[navController pushViewController:homeScreen animated:YES];
```

**You have added the homeScreen to navigation controller, and again trying to push the same controller.**

Your root view controller( welcomeVC) doesn't have navigation controller,So it can't push any view controller (**it can only present,hence the second code blocked worked for you**). You have to present the navigation controller from welcome VC which has home screen as root view controller.

Or

You need to add the navigation controller as root view controller( which has the WelcomeVC in the navigation stack) in your app delegate and then let it push the homeVC in the welcomeVC by simply calling the:

```
[self.navigationController pushview....
```

AppDelegate: Set the navigation controller as root view controller in here:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

       WelcomeVC *mainViewController = [[WelcomeVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"WelcomeVC" bundle:nil]; 
       UINavigationController *navController =  [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: mainViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

and then push to your wished controller:

```
 HomeScreenVC *homeScreen = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenVC" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeScreen animated:YES];
```

Comment: 2016-02-12 00:26:09.151 MyApp[39931:821657] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fab9a663720> on <WelcomeVC: 0x7fab9a53fa80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: NOw I get this message log and got black screen

Comment: where are you calling the [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeScreen animated:YES]; ?